# How to redirect to another domain while clicking on chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the asp.net chart control.

I need to redirect to a url of another domain by clicking an X-axis value or series that should open as a new window. I used to `Series.Points[index].url = "http://www.domainxxx.com/abc.aspx?abcvalue=1000"`.

How can I open it as a new window?

Comment: can we please see the code?

Answer (score 1):

Add the target attribute to open in new window:

```
$("SeriesId").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: The chart points are added foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> category in dicPCategories)
            {
                string strTempKey = category.Key;
                series.Points.AddXY(strTempKey, category.Value); }
Here how do I implement redirection.

Comment: please have a look how the html code is generating for your graph point , add then add common class for all use  $(".Class Name").attr("target", "_blank");